# How do Install CentOS on home server?

Tags: linux, centos

I'm still a total noob so please bear with me. I built my own computer, pretty simple 4 gigs of ram, i7 processor, 1TB hard drive, and I am trying to image it with CentOS so I can have my own server for a college project I am working on. So far I have found the download page on the Stanford.edu site for CentOS, but I am wondering what is the extension do I want first of all? .iso or .torrent. Secondly what type of architecture am I looking for i386 or x86? If someone could direct me to a pretty nice step by step how to that would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your computer is an i7, you have your choice of either using a i386 version or an x86_64 version.    The i386 usually means its 32bit and the x86_64 are 64bit.  Either version will install fine on your machine, its just depends on if you want 64bit os or 32bit os.  As geermc4 said, iso is the file you want to download.  The iso will give you a dvd/cd image that you can burn to disc and boot with to install centos.   May i suggest reading [centos installation guide](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Installation_Guide/) for more information on installing centos.

Answer (score 1):

.torrent just means you'll need a torrent client to get your .iso, if you go for .iso you're downloading directly from they're site, .torrent would probably be faster, architecture, depends on your CPU, i386 is the safest bet here, as for guide, maybe [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/installation-guide-centos5.1-desktop) can help